# How can I use RequestHeader with actuator endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have customized my actuator/info endpoint and I want to use information from the header to authorize a `RestTemplate` call to another service.

I am implementing the InfoContributor as here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-info-actuator-custom

I want to accept request headers in the `contribute()` method. For any user defined REST endpoint, I can define a `@RequestHeader` parameter and access headers.

But unfortunately, the `InfoContributor`'s `contribute()` method takes only one parameter.

How can I access a request header inside the `contribute()` method?

Comment: Don't forget to tag your questions with `spring-boot` as many will be following `spring-boot` tag and you will get quicker answer. Your original question didn't have that tag. It was only added yesterday by Micheal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can autowire `HttpServletRequest` into your `InfoContributor`

```
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

    @Component
    public class Custom implements InfoContributor {

       @Autowired
       private HttpServletRequest request;

       @Override
       public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
          ...
          request.getHeader("your header");
          ...
       }
    }
```

- Or you can use `RequestContextHolder` to get hold of it

```
@Component
public class Custom implements InfoContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        ...
        HttpServletRequest request = 
           ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                        .getRequest();
        request.getHeader("your header");
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use your first approach , would't it create a singleton of request object ? My application will be accessed by multiple users.

Comment: It will be singleton bean of `Custom` class. However spring will inject `request` is request scoped proxy so every request will  be pointing to its own `HttpServletRequest`.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html